# M2: How to get Customer Cart Rules in My Account page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I want to filter **cart rules** list in **my account** page.
I've list cart rules in **My Account** page "Dashboard". But I want to filter **cart rules** list by condition.

[image: Cart Rules List]

I've configure the conditions in cart rules by **date of birth**.  I just want to show the rules if the customer date of birth is same with my conditions.

I got the Data from `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info`. but I dont know how to filter cart rules list.

```
$datax = $helper->getSalesRule();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($datax->getData());
echo '</pre>';
```

and the result

```
[  
    conditions_serialized
]=>{  
   "type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine",
   "attribute":null,
   "operator":null,
   "value":"1",
   "is_value_processed":null,
   "aggregator":"all",
   "conditions":[  
   {  
"type":"Magento\\CustomerSegment\\Model\\Segment\\Condition\\Segment",
     "attribute":false,
     "operator":"==",
     "value":"138,110",
     "is_value_processed":false
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the collection of all rules, then validate those by using validate() function

```
$rules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection()

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            $rule->afterLoad();
            if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
                $address = $quote->getBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            }
            foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $item) {// total_qty - allowed only in total collection process
                $address->setTotalQty($address->getTotalQty() + $item->getQty());
            }
            if ($rule->validate($address)) {
                $subtotal = 0;
                foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($rule->getConditions()->validate($item)) {
                        $subtotal += $item->getBasePrice() * $item->getQty();
                    }
                }
                if ($subtotal > 0) {
                    return $rule;
                }
            }
        }
```